# Is there a limit on the data that is returned from stackoverflow API calls?

Tags: support, api-v2

I have the following query, which is identical to the example they give in the documentation:

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?fromdate=1391756400&order=desc&site=stackoverflow&sort=activity&tagged=c%2B%2B

This (should) return all of the questions with that tag....but for some reason, in the JSON data, I only get the first 30. Is there a reason for this? Since I'm not explicitly specifying page size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API allows you to set a `pagesize` of 0 to 100 (with the exception of the `/sites` route, which allows larger values), and defaults to a maximum of 30 items in the response.

To get all of the items applicable to the API query, you need to check the `has_more` field to determine if you need to request subsequent pages via the `page` parameter. This is covered in more detail in the [API documentation's section on paging](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging).

Comment: I actually should have listed this in my original question, but I passed `has_more=true` inside the query string..and still got the same results. Maybe I need to do it via a filter instead.

Comment: `has_more` is returned in the response, it indicates you need to make another call with `page=n` to get more results. The most you'll get back with a single request is 100, assuming you set the `pagesize` to that.

Comment: Oooh, okay. Got it. That makes sense. I originally thought it was a wrapper variable the requestor gives. Thanks